# Apple Bonjour service bound to localhost

Tags: c++, windows, networking, bonjour, dns-sd

I have a TCP socket bound to `127.0.0.1`, and I want to make it available as a service on the local machine. The problem however is that Bonjour uses the DHCP address instead of localhost, even with `kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly` set as the interface. This prevents me from actually connecting to the socket.

So how do I make it so that the service resolves to `127.0.0.1` rather than `192.168.xxx.xxx`?

I am using the latest bonjour SDK for windows in C++, although it should work the same on all operating systems.

Currently I am only using the following function call to register the service:

```
DNSServiceRef ref = m_Impl->m_ConnectionRef.get();
DNSServiceRegister(&ref, kDNSServiceFlagsShareConnection, // Handles and flags
    kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexLocalOnly, a_Name.c_str(), a_Service.GetServiceType().c_str(), nullptr, // Service name and type
    nullptr, HostToBigEndian(a_Service.GetPort()), // Host address
    static_cast<uint16>(a_Service.GetTXTRecord().GetRecord().length()), a_Service.GetTXTRecord().GetRecord().c_str(), // TXT record
    &MDNSServiceManagerImpl::StaticDNSServiceRegisterReply, service.get()); // Callback
```

I tried passing `"127.0.0.1"` as the host name instead of `nullptr`, but as the API comments say, you will then have to manually add the records, and this is where I get lost.

Comment: Can you add more detail like what is Bonjour (link) because they are a lot of thing call "bonjour", add some code ?

Comment: The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dnssd/1804733-dnsserviceregister) says that it take the host name. How do you test the connection  ? What is your host name ? Have you try 0.0.0.0 (accept all ip carefull with that)  ? Have you try to connect with localhost or host name ?